# Убрать экранирование кавычек js

Tags: javascript

В общем проблема: получаю массив из *localStorage*, вывожу, и двойные кавычки в которые обрамлены элементы массива, автоматически экранируются, как это убрать?

```
localStorage.setItem('idsGTag', JSON.parse(idsGTag));
localStorage.setItem('totalGTag', JSON.stringify(totalGTag));
var idsGTag = localStorage.getItem('idsGTag');
var totalGTag = localStorage.getItem('totalGTag');
```

У меня ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0. Но если я просто получаю переменные из хранилища и вывожу в консоли, то все ок. parse и stringify я намеренно использую, чтоб посмотреть результат обеих

Comment: подозреваю при получении нужно использовать `JSON.parse`

Comment: наверно , я делаю что то не так. localStorage.setItem('idsGTag', JSON.parse(idsGTag));
localStorage.setItem('totalGTag', JSON.stringify(totalGTag));
var idsGTag = localStorage.getItem('idsGTag');
var totalGTag = localStorage.getItem('totalGTag');    У меня ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0.  Но если я просто получаю переменные из хронилища и вывожу в консоле, то все ок.  parse и stringify я намеренно использую, чтоб посмотреть результат обеих

Answer (score 2, accepted):

правильное решение имеет такой код.
у меня так получилось

1. получаем переменную из локального хранилища

   ```
   var P1= localStorage.getItem('perem1');
   var P2= localStorage.getItem('perem2');
   ```
2. делаем json parse

   ```
   var gid = JSON.parse(P1);
   var gpr = JSON.parse(P2);
   ```
3. работаем с переменными *gid* and *gpr*